# plagiarism detector python flask error method not found

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a plagiarism detection tool using flask and python and I am getting the error "Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL.". The project allows a user to upload two files to be compared. Whenever I click on the submit button in the html form then the above error occurs. Can you please suggest some changes?

```py
from io import FileIO
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask.helpers import url_for
from werkzeug.utils import redirect, secure_filename
import os
import numpy as np

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload():
    if request.method == "POST":
        f1 = request.files['file1']
        f2 = request.files['file2']
        return redirect(url_for('user'))
    else:
        return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route("/")
def user():
    return f"<h1>success</h1>"

if __name__=='__main__':
      app.run(debug=True)
```

my html code snippet from upload.html is:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label for="file1">Upload first file here:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1"><br><br>
    <label for="file2">Upload second file here:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file2" name="file2"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an action in your form. In your implementation, it tries to send a POST request to home(), not upload(). That's why you're getting Method not allowed message.

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label for="file1">Upload first file here:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1"><br><br>
    <label for="file2">Upload second file here:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file2" name="file2"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```